# for loop does not terminate on false condition

Tags: arrays, c, loops, for-loop

The `for` loop should iterate only 5 times but first `for` loop is iterating 6 times but seconds works correctly with same condition.

```
    int i, j, n = 5;
    int *p;
    printf("enter size of array=");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    p = (int *)calloc(sizeof(int), n);  

    printf("enter array\n");

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d ", (p + i));
    }

    printf("array\n");

    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        printf("%d ", *(p + j));
    }
    free(p);
```

Comment: Type "something stupid" for the 5th scanf value ... instead of "42<ENTER>" something like "42foobar<ENTER>"

Comment: Some recommend not to use scanf in the first place. Its a bit like being tied to a dead camel in the middle of the desert. It sounds exciting at first but grows tedious quickly. A way to do, less prone to surprises is to use `fgets()` and then use functions like `strtol` etc.

Comment: We do not usually write `(p + i)` or `*(p + j)` - the idiomatic way to write these is to use the array subscript operator, `&p[i]` and `p[j]`.

Answer (score 0):

The number of iterations of both loops is determined by the first number input at the prompt `enter size of array=`.

You should be more defensive: reject invalid input and detect errors.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int i, n;
    int *p;

    printf("Enter array size: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n <= 0) {
        printf("invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    p = (int *)calloc(sizeof(int), n);
    if (p == NULL) {
        printf("allocation failure\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("enter array\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d ", (p + i)) != 1) {
            printf("invalid input\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    printf("array\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d ", *(p + i));
    }
    printf("\n");
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hey @harsh you didn't made mistake in pointers point of view.
but the problem is cause by scanf.

As you have provided '_' (a blank space)( scanf("%d ", (p + i)) ) after %d ;
then scanf will always finds a space(or any spacing character) after a each occurences of provided value and iterates a one more time in search of that hence it will run one more occurence last time.

just remove that space, it'll work.
Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

do

> ```
> scanf ("%d", (p+i))
> ```

ie, do not give space after %d

also syntax of calloc should be

> p = (int *)calloc(n, sizeof(int));

Comment: Can you tell me reason why we should not give a space in scanf after %d........please share with me

Comment: @HarshGour when you do "%d " in scanf, the scanf does not quit after getting an integer, because within the scanf you have not given only %d, you have also given a blank space. so scanf waits for some other values even when you press ENTER. The first scanf waits till 2 inputs. within your first for loop, just before the scanf, write "printf ("Iteration no. %d", i);". This will show you the number of iterations of the loop. You will see that the 1st (or 0th) scanf will exit after taking 2 inputs.